# group list elements if they share a common element

Tags: scala

I have a list of strings. The elements are comprised of two letters. For Example,

```
val A = List("bf", "dc", "ab", "af")
```

I want to collect all the letters that share a common letter, i.e.,

```
"bf" and "af" share "f"
```

into a tuple

```
("a", "b", "f")
```

the other tuple would  be

```
("c", "d")
```

so I want to return a list that looks like this

```
List(List("a", "b", "f"), List("c", "d"))
```

I got my intended result with

```
val A= List("bf", "dc", "ab", "af")

val B= A.flatMap(x => x.split("")).distinct

B.map(y => A.map(x => if(x.contains(y)) {x} else {""}).filter(_ !="").flatMap(_.split("")).distinct.sorted).distinct
```

but there must be a better way.

Comment: What would be the expected result if `val A = List("bf", "fc", "ab", "af")`?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not bad, but can be simplified.

You don't have to split the strings and flatMap then. You can just flatten the List of Strings.

`A.map(x => if(x.contains(y)) {x} else {""}).filter(_!="")`
It would be better to write:

`A.flatMap(x => if(x.contains(y)) Some(x) else None)` or

`A.filter(_.contains(y))`

But you can use partition and count to express it, here is my solution:

```scala
val a = List("bf", "dc", "ab", "af")

val b = a.flatten.distinct.sorted

b.partition(x => a.count(_.contains(x)) > 1)
```

Comment: That's true... I misunderstood it. Still my other comments can be useful

Answer (score 0):

I am curious, "*better*" in what sense? If you care about algorithm complexity in terms of Big O, then assuming the following:

- the alphabet is simple, let it be 26 letters;
- the strings are of arbitrary length, but much smaller than the input's length `n`.

Then you can do it in O(n):

```
def fn(in: Iterator[String]) = {
  val a = Array.fill(26)(-1)

  for {s <- in} {
    val cl = s.toSeq.map(_ - 'a')
    val i = cl.map(a(_)).find(_ >= 0) getOrElse cl.head
    cl.foreach(a(_) = i)
  }

  a.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 > 0).groupBy(_._1).values.map {
    _.map(_._2+'a').map(_.toChar)
  }
}

scala> fn(List("bf", "dc", "ab", "af").toIterator)
res17: Iterable[Array[Char]] = List(Array(a, b, f), Array(c, d))
```

Back to "*better*". If you wanted a nifty FP solution, then some may say that we sacrifice FP here, because used a mutable variable.
It's arguable, since that mutable variable is scoped inside and the function is still pure.